# What is wrong with this SQLite create Statement in AndroidStudio

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can anyone decipher what's wrong with this method? The log says that there's is a syntax error but I'm not able to see it.

Here's the code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String createTable = "CREATE_TABLE " + MOVIES_DB + "("
                + TITLE + " TEXT, "
                + OVERVIEW + " TEXT, "
                + POSTER_PATH + " TEXT, "
                + RELEASE_DATE + " TEXT, "
                + ORIGINAL_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                + ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE + " TEXT, "
                + BACKDROP_PATH + " TEXT, "
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  "
                + VOTE_COUNT + " TEXT, "
                + POPULARITY + " TEXT, "
                + VOTE_AVERAGE + " TEXT, "
                + ADULT + " TEXT, "
                + VIDEO + " TEXT, "
                + GENRE_IDS + " TEXT, "
                + HISTORY_USER + " TEXT, "
                + WATCH_LATER + " TEXT, "
                + FAVORITE_FLAG + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0"
                + ")";


        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);
    }
```

It used to work. I added the `FAVORITE_FLAG` and now it doesn't run. I also tried with `INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` after `FAVORITE_FLAG`

Comment: `CREATE_TABLE` needs a space and not a `_`

Comment: Thank you very much juergen.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Juergen D, `CREATE TABLE` take a space and not and underscore.

Take a look at the [`CREATE TABLE` Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for SQLite.

BTW; try to put your `id` / PK declaration first, as it's the common practice (and more logical)

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/24e04/2)

**SQLite (SQL.js) Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES_DB(
"ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
"TITLE" TEXT, 
"OVERVIEW" TEXT, 
"POSTER_PATH" TEXT, 
"RELEASE_DATE" TEXT, 
"ORIGINAL_TITLE" TEXT, 
"ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE" TEXT, 
"BACKDROP_PATH" TEXT, 
"VOTE_COUNT" TEXT, 
"POPULARITY" TEXT, 
"VOTE_AVERAGE" TEXT, 
"ADULT" TEXT, 
"VIDEO" TEXT, 
"GENRE_IDS" TEXT, 
"HISTORY_USER" TEXT, 
"WATCH_LATER" TEXT, 
"FAVORITE_FLAG" INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

Insert into MOVIES_DB Values(1,"test","test","test 7",
    "test","test 12","test","test","test","test","test",
    "test","test","test","test","test",2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ID, TITLE, FAVORITE_FLAG from MOVIES_DB
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/24e04/2/0)**:

```
| ID | TITLE | FAVORITE_FLAG |
|----|-------|---------------|
|  1 |  test |             2 |
```